# Running delayed_job worker on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, terminal, delayed-job

So right now I have an implementation of delayed_job that works perfectly on my local development environment. In order to start the worker on my machine, I just run `rake jobs:work` and it works perfectly.

To get delayed_job to work on heroku, I've been using pretty much the same command: `heroku run rake jobs:work`. This solution works, without me having to pay anything for worker costs to Heroku, but I have to keep my command prompt window open or else the delayed_job worker stops when I close it. Is there a command to permanently keep this delayed_job worker working even when I close the command window? Or is there another better way to go about this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add

```
worker: rake jobs:work
```

to your `Procfile`.

**EDIT:**

Even if you run it from your console you 'buy' worker dyno but Heroku has per second biling. So you don't pay because you have 750h free, and month in worst case has 744h, so you have free 6h for your extra dynos, scheduler tasks and so on.

Comment: Even if you run it from your console you 'buy' worker dyno but Heroku has per second biling, so you don't pay because you have 750h free, and month in worst case has 744h, so you have free 6h for your extra dynos, scheduler tasks and so on.

Answer (score 13):

I recommend the [workless gem](https://github.com/lostboy/workless) to run delayed jobs on heroku. I use this now - it works perfectly for me, zero hassle and at zero cost.

I have also used [hirefireapp](http://hirefireapp.com/) which gives a much finer degree of control on scaling workers. This costs, but costs less than a single heroku worker (over a month). I don't use this now, but have used it, and it worked very well.

Comment: I installed workless and configured the heroku variables. What should I do now? It doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: did you add the config (assuming you're on cedar)?

    config.after_initialize do 
      Delayed::Job.scaler = :heroku_cedar
    end

Comment: @DamonMannion +5 for you on this answer

Comment: @Damon I tried it, even added the code you posted, but it simply doesn't work... :|

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it personally yet, but you might find `nohup` useful. It allows your process to run even though you have closed your terminal window. Link: http://linux.101hacks.com/unix/nohup-command/

Answer (score 0):

Using heroku console to get workers onto the jobs will only create create a temporary dyno for the job. To keep the jobs running without cli, you need to put the command into the Procfile as @Lucaksz suggested.

After deployment, you also need to scale the dyno formation, as heroku need to know how many dyno should be put onto the process type like this: 
**heroku ps:scale worker=1**

More details can be read here https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scaling